# Windows logo key+number don't work with more than one open programs

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcuts

I work with several windows, several programs at the same time. Sometimes more than 20 at once. My workflow becomes to heavily use Windows logo key+number to jump from one to another.

Example: I have Outlook and a mail open. If I tick two times Windows logo key+number -> it gets me directly to that mail. Recently this tactic doesn't work anymore. I just see a bar, if I hover the mouse I see all windows.

[image: Screenshot]

I use 7+ Taskbar Tweaker on all of my machines, but just one makes trouble. I uninstalled it already.

Don't know what to do, just went me crazy already.

Anyone out there an idea? I am using overall WIN10.

Thank you.

Comment: How's the image related to the question?

Comment: You can see on that image on top right the bar I only see. Normally should here be there the thumbs of the windows. The huge font is part of my wallpaper (I admit not the best one for this question)

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that Windows logo key + CTRL + NR works ALWAYS.

The only miss is the preview of the window I jump in.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I have a workaround to fix my problem.

[image]

Before: I press WIN Key + NR => I got just a blank bar

After: I press WIN Key + NR => I can jump from window to window again

This will also reset the folder view for all folders at once and delete any custom per-folder views!

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to the following key:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
3. Delete the Bags subkey

[image]

4. Go to the following key:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell

Delete the Bags subkey here too.

5. Now navigate to:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam
6. Again, delete the Bags subkey.
7. Restart the Explorer shell.